# Cucumber JVM: Cannot get access to ScenarioOutline in @After hooks

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using Cucumber JVM with Selenium and I would like to reuse the browser within Scenario Outlines.  In order to do this, I was hoping I'd have access to the Scenario Outline in the @Before and @After hooks so I would know if I was still within the same Scenario Outline and if I had reached the last line of the Scenario Outline.  Is there a way to do this? I only see a way to get the Scenario. I can tell from the name of the Scenario that it is part of a Scenario Outline, but I don't see a way to know if I'm on the last Scenario to know to close the browser at the end instead of reuse.

Update:
I have implemented the following example to reuse the same browser for all the tests in order to speed up execution time since closing and restarting the browser can add a lot of extra time: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java

This has got me headed in the right direction, but to add more efficiency, I would like to be able to know when I'm in a Scenario Outline as opposed to a Scenario, so that I can write custom code to stay logged in as to not only reuse the browser, but to not have to login again and navigate to the element under test, saving even more time.

Cucumber offers @After hooks as follows

```
@After
public void runAfterEveryScenario(Scenario scenario){
    //do something with scenario
}
```

I'd like to be able to determine in an after hook if I am within a ScenarioOutline so I can stay logged in between tests, or log out if not.

This is a simplified example of one of my outlines I would only want to run the log in step for the first scenario of the outline and only run the @After hook for log out after the last scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Grid Content Validation
    Given I log in
    When I navigate page
    And I select <allocation> grid
    Then Grid should be correctly displayed by <allocation>
    Examples:
    | allocation |
    | choice1    |
    | choice2    |
    | choice3    |
    | choice4    |
    | choice5    |
```

Comment: Can you share the code you are trying to get running? An example would make perhaps it easier to understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to store the browser reference in a static variable that you don’t recreate. This could lead to other strange behaviour so I’m not sure it is a good idea.